# two-way binding - nested object - angular - Cannot read property of undefined

Tags: angular, two-way-binding, nest-nested-object

I want to use [(ngModel)] for a nested object, but is giving me an error

`Cannot read property 'mxn' of undefined`

these are the data structure of my models:

company.model.ts

```
import Currency from './currency.model';

class Company {
_id: string;
name: string;
maxLimit: number;
source: [string];
deliveryMethod: [string];
currency: Currency;
date: Date;

constructor() {
    this.name = '';
    this.date = new Date();
    this.maxLimit = 0;
    this.source = [''];
    this.deliveryMethod = [''];
    this.currency.mxn = 0;
    this.currency.php = 0;
    }
}

export default Company;
```

currency.model.ts

```
class Currency {
mxn: number;
php: number;


constructor() {
    this.mxn = 0;
    this.php = 0;
}
}

export default Currency;
```

and this is part of company.ts

```
public newCompany: Company = new Company();
companiesList: Company[];
editcompanies: Company[] = [];
```

and HTML

in HTML page I'm able to show the `mxn` value by just using :

```
<tr class="companies" *ngFor="let company of companiesList">
{{company.currency.mxn}}
```

but when I want to use it with `ngModel` two-way binding for updating the value and sending it to the database it doesn't work.

`[(ngModel)] = "newCompany.currency.mxn"` 
it produces the mentioned error above. 
if I use 
`[(ngModel)] = "newCompany.currency"` it doesn't give me an error but the code it's useless since i can't assign any value to `mxn`.

I have to say that `[(ngModel)] = "newCompany.name"` it works fine with this and I can update the name.

the backend works fine as I tried it with Postman. the problem is angular side.

so the question is if my data structure is correct how can I use two-way binding for the nested object?

Comment: shouldn't you first instantiate the currency member in the company class constructor?

Comment: Thanks, you were all correct. it worked by just instantiating the currency.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
currency: Currency;
...
constructor() {
  ...
  this.currency.mxn = 0;
  this.currency.php = 0;
}
```

mxn and php do not exist yet until you instantiate an instance of `Currency`. The instance `currency` is null. It doesn't contain any properties.

```
currency: Currency;
...
constructor() {
  ...
  this.currency = new Currency(); // invoke Currency constructor, create mxn and php with value 0, therefore you dont need this.currency.mxn = 0 and same to php
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A slight change in your Company model should be enough:

```js
class Company {
  _id: string;
  name: string;
  maxLimit: number;
  source: [string];
  deliveryMethod: [string];
  currency: Currency = new Currency(); // provide an instance, otherwise this field will be undefined
  date: Date;

  constructor() {
      this.name = '';
      this.date = new Date();
      this.maxLimit = 0;
      this.source = [''];
      this.deliveryMethod = [''];
      this.currency.mxn = 0;
      this.currency.php = 0;
      }
  }

export default Company;
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're not instantiating the currency field in your constructor. Try by changing the

```
currency: Currency;
```

to

```
currency = new Currency();
```

It's probably working with your `companiesList` because probably (I'm guessing here) your backend instantiate them for you. And when you instantiate the `newCompany` which I assume you do by yourself it's not working cause of the missing `new Currency()`